# Python Tkinter changing StringVar value to use it as a background indicator on a UI

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I'm building a UI where the users have to select some dates. I've added a row called `Date Indicator` which shows a box with a color. The starting color (until the user selects both dates) is `grey`. This color has to change depending on the dates that the user selects.

- If he selects two dates where the days between them are **more than two weeks**, the box has to became **green**.
- If he selects two dates where the days between them are **less than two weeks**, the box has to became **yellow**.
  If he selects two dates where the days between them are less **than one week**, the box has to became **red**.

This is a Photoshoped result for the desired solution:
[image]

The code seems to be long, but you only have to check it until the `tkCalendar` class. From there to the bottom is just the calendar code you dont need to change. (And yes, there are some `imports` you dont need to use for this code, I maintain them because I've to use them for other stuff, but you can remove them)

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import os
from Tkinter import *
import Image
import ImageTk
import tkFileDialog
import xlrd
import csv
from tkMessageBox import *
from win32com.client import Dispatch
import datetime
import time
import calendar

year = time.localtime()[0]
month = time.localtime()[1]
day =time.localtime()[2]
strdate = (str(year) +  "/" + str(month) + "/" + str(day))

fnta = ("Helvetica", 10)
fnt = ("Helvetica", 10)
fntc = ("Helvetica", 10, 'bold')


strtitle = "Calendario"
strdays= "Do  Lu  Ma  Mi  Ju  Vi  Sa"
dictmonths = {'1':'Ene','2':'Feb','3':'Mar','4':'Abr','5':'May',
    '6':'Jun','7':'Jul','8':'Ago','9':'Sep','10':'Oct','11':'Nov',
    '12':'Dic'}


class Planificador(Frame):
    def __init__(self,master):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.master = master
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.master.title("Planner")
        self.frameOne = Frame(self.master)
        self.frameOne.grid(row=0,column=0)
        self.frameTwo = Frame(self.master)
        self.frameTwo.grid(row=0, column=1)
        self.frameThree = Frame(self.master)
        self.frameThree.grid(row=0, column=2)

        self.frameFour = Frame(self.master)
        self.frameFour.grid(row=1,column=0, sticky=N)
        self.frameFive = Frame(self.master)
        self.frameFive.grid(row=1, column=1)
        self.frameSix = Frame(self.master)
        self.frameSix.grid(row=1, column=2, sticky=N)

        self.frameSeven = Frame(self.master)
        self.frameSeven.grid(row=2,column=0)
        self.frameEight = Frame(self.master)
        self.frameEight.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky=S)
        self.frameNine = Frame(self.master)
        self.frameNine.grid(row=2, column=2)

        self.start_date_menu()

    def start_date_menu(self):
        self.initial_num_elements = 4
        self.TEXT_MENU_ROW = 0  # initial date menu grid row
        self.COL_WIDTH = 10  # width of each subcolumn of dates

        for frame in (self.frameFour, self.frameSix):
            self.dayintext = Label(frame, text="Day in",
                                        width=self.COL_WIDTH, justify="center")
            self.dayintext.grid(row=self.TEXT_MENU_ROW, column=0)
            self.dayouttext = Label(frame, text="Day out", width=self.COL_WIDTH,
                                   justify="center")
            self.dayouttext.grid(row=self.TEXT_MENU_ROW, column=1)
            self.status = Label(frame, text="Date indicator", width=self.COL_WIDTH,
                                   justify="center")
            self.status.grid(row=self.TEXT_MENU_ROW, column=2)

        self.dates = [self.create_all_entrys(aux_index)
                        for aux_index in xrange(self.initial_num_elements)]

        self.anadirpiezas = Button(self.frameEight, text="add more",
                                   command=self.addone, width=self.COL_WIDTH)
        self.anadirpiezas.grid(row=0, column=3)


    def addone(self):
        self.dates.append(self.create_all_entrys(len(self.dates)))
        self.printdates()

    def printdates(self):
        print "IN:"
        for i in xrange(self.initial_num_elements):
            print self.dates[i][0].get() # col 0
        print "OUT:"
        for i in xrange(self.initial_num_elements):
            print self.dates[i][2].get() # col 2

    def create_all_entrys(self, aux_index):
        menu_col = aux_index % 2  # left/right column of the date frame
        menu_row = self.TEXT_MENU_ROW + aux_index/2 + 1
        frame = self.frameSix if aux_index % 2 else self.frameFour

        in_var = StringVar(value="--------")
        in_btn = Button(frame, textvariable=in_var, width=self.COL_WIDTH,
                        command=lambda v=in_var: self.fnCalendar(v))
        in_btn.grid(row=menu_row, column=0)

        out_var = StringVar(value="--------")
        out_btn = Button(frame, textvariable=out_var, width=self.COL_WIDTH,
                         command=lambda v=out_var: self.fnCalendar(v))
        out_btn.grid(row=menu_row, column=1)

        self.colorvar = StringVar()
        self.colorvar.set('grey')
        self.status_color = Label(frame, width=2, bg=self.colorvar.get())
        self.status_color.grid(row=menu_row,column=2)

        return in_var, in_btn, out_var, out_btn

    def fnCalendar(self, datebar):
        tkCalendar(self.master, year, month, day, datebar)

class tkCalendar :
  def __init__ (self, master, arg_year, arg_month, arg_day,
       arg_parent_updatable_var):
    print arg_parent_updatable_var.get()
    self.update_var = arg_parent_updatable_var
    top = self.top = Toplevel(master)
    top.title("Choose a date")
    try : self.intmonth = int(arg_month)
    except: self.intmonth = int(1)
    self.canvas =Canvas (top, width =200, height =220,
      relief =RIDGE, background ="#ece9d8", borderwidth =0)
    self.canvas.create_rectangle(0,0,303,30, fill="#ece9d8",width=0 )
    self.canvas.create_text(100,17, text="Choose!",  font=fntc, fill="#BA1111")
    stryear = str(arg_year)

    self.year_var=StringVar()
    self.year_var.set(stryear)
    self.lblYear = Label(top, textvariable = self.year_var,
        font = fnta, background="#ece9d8")
    self.lblYear.place(x=85, y = 30)

    self.month_var=StringVar()
    strnummonth = str(self.intmonth)
    strmonth = dictmonths[strnummonth]
    self.month_var.set(strmonth)

    self.lblYear = Label(top, textvariable = self.month_var,
        font = fnta, background="#ece9d8")
    self.lblYear.place(x=85, y = 50)
    #Variable muy usada
    tagBaseButton = "Arrow"
    self.tagBaseNumber = "DayButton"
    #draw year arrows
    x,y = 40, 43
    tagThisButton = "leftyear"
    tagFinalThisButton = tuple((tagBaseButton,tagThisButton))
    self.fnCreateLeftArrow(self.canvas, x,y, tagFinalThisButton)
    x,y = 150, 43
    tagThisButton = "rightyear"
    tagFinalThisButton = tuple((tagBaseButton,tagThisButton))
    self.fnCreateRightArrow(self.canvas, x,y, tagFinalThisButton)
    #draw month arrows
    x,y = 40, 63
    tagThisButton = "leftmonth"
    tagFinalThisButton = tuple((tagBaseButton,tagThisButton))
    self.fnCreateLeftArrow(self.canvas, x,y, tagFinalThisButton)
    x,y = 150, 63
    tagThisButton = "rightmonth"
    tagFinalThisButton = tuple((tagBaseButton,tagThisButton))
    self.fnCreateRightArrow(self.canvas, x,y, tagFinalThisButton)
    #Print days
    self.canvas.create_text(100,90, text=strdays, font=fnta)
    self.canvas.pack (expand =1, fill =BOTH)
    self.canvas.tag_bind ("Arrow", "<ButtonRelease-1>", self.fnClick)
    self.canvas.tag_bind ("Arrow", "<Enter>", self.fnOnMouseOver)
    self.canvas.tag_bind ("Arrow", "<Leave>", self.fnOnMouseOut)
    self.fnFillCalendar()

  def fnCreateRightArrow(self, canv, x, y, strtagname):
    canv.create_polygon(x,y, [[x+0,y-5], [x+10, y-5] , [x+10,y-10] ,
        [x+20,y+0], [x+10,y+10] , [x+10,y+5] , [x+0,y+5]],
        tags = strtagname , fill="black", width=0)

  def fnCreateLeftArrow(self, canv, x, y, strtagname):
    canv.create_polygon(x,y, [[x+10,y-10], [x+10, y-5] , [x+20,y-5] ,
        [x+20,y+5], [x+10,y+5] , [x+10,y+10] ],
        tags = strtagname , fill="black", width=0)


  def fnClick(self,event):
    owntags =self.canvas.gettags(CURRENT)
    if "rightyear" in owntags:
    intyear = int(self.year_var.get())
    intyear +=1
    stryear = str(intyear)
    self.year_var.set(stryear)
    if "leftyear" in owntags:
    intyear = int(self.year_var.get())
    intyear -=1
    stryear = str(intyear)
    self.year_var.set(stryear)
    if "rightmonth" in owntags:
    if self.intmonth < 12 :
        self.intmonth += 1
        strnummonth = str(self.intmonth)
        strmonth = dictmonths[strnummonth]
        self.month_var.set(strmonth)
    else :
        self.intmonth = 1
        strnummonth = str(self.intmonth)
        strmonth = dictmonths[strnummonth]
        self.month_var.set(strmonth)
        intyear = int(self.year_var.get())
        intyear +=1
        stryear = str(intyear)
        self.year_var.set(stryear)
    if "leftmonth" in owntags:
    if self.intmonth > 1 :
        self.intmonth -= 1
        strnummonth = str(self.intmonth)
        strmonth = dictmonths[strnummonth]
        self.month_var.set(strmonth)
    else :
        self.intmonth = 12
        strnummonth = str(self.intmonth)
        strmonth = dictmonths[strnummonth]
        self.month_var.set(strmonth)
        intyear = int(self.year_var.get())
        intyear -=1
        stryear = str(intyear)
        self.year_var.set(stryear)
    self.fnFillCalendar()
  def fnFillCalendar(self):
    init_x_pos = 20
    arr_y_pos = [110,130,150,170,190,210]
    intposarr = 0
    self.canvas.delete("DayButton")
    self.canvas.update()
    intyear = int(self.year_var.get())
    monthcal = calendar.monthcalendar(intyear, self.intmonth)
    for row in monthcal:
    xpos = init_x_pos
    ypos = arr_y_pos[intposarr]
    for item in row:
        stritem = str(item)
        if stritem == "0":
        xpos += 27
        else :
        tagNumber = tuple((self.tagBaseNumber,stritem))
        self.canvas.create_text(xpos, ypos , text=stritem,
            font=fnta,tags=tagNumber)
            xpos += 27
    intposarr += 1
    self.canvas.tag_bind ("DayButton", "<ButtonRelease-1>", self.fnClickNumber)
    self.canvas.tag_bind ("DayButton", "<Enter>", self.fnOnMouseOver)
    self.canvas.tag_bind ("DayButton", "<Leave>", self.fnOnMouseOut)

  def fnClickNumber(self,event):
    owntags =self.canvas.gettags(CURRENT)
    for x in owntags:
    if (x == "current") or (x == "DayButton"): pass
    else :
        strdate = (str(self.year_var.get()) + "/" +
            str(self.intmonth) + "/" +
            str(x))
        self.update_var.set(strdate)
        self.top.withdraw()

  def fnOnMouseOver(self,event):
    self.canvas.move(CURRENT, 1, 1)
    self.canvas.update()

  def fnOnMouseOut(self,event):
    self.canvas.move(CURRENT, -1, -1)
    self.canvas.update()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk()
    aplicacion = Planificador(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

I'm totally lost trying to do this. I know I've to change `self.colorvar` but I dont know how to do it. I tryed to `self.colorvar.set('red')` for example but I cant make it work the way I explaned above. The `in` and `out` dates can be found on the `printdates` function. You help is much appreciated.

Comment: your question mentions `self.colorbar`, yet `colorbar` appears nowhere in your code.

Answer (score 7):

I don't think you can link the bg option to a StringVar. You can only do it with the option textvariable. The way you should do it is via the Label.config() method.

So you could write:

```
self.status_color.config(bg='red')
```

or, if you want to keep using the colorvar:

```
self.colorvar.set('red')
self.status_color.config(bg=self.colorvar.get())
```

That should work, and I guess that you can figure out the 2 week thing.

**EDIT**:

You can also 'link' the StringVar self.colorvar to a function that changes self.status_color (with the [trace](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/variable.htm) method); so that whenever colorvar is changed, your function will be called and it will change the status color.
This is my suggestion:

```
def myFunc(*args):
    self.status_color.config(bg=self.colorvar.get())

self.colorvar.trace('w',self.myFunc)
```

Now every time you call self.colorvar.set(), you will be also calling self.myFunc.

**EDIT:**

As for the week thing, I'm not going to answer completely as it seems easy. Just get an integer for month and day of IN and OUT and do something like this:

```
monthdiff = monthout-monthin
if monthdiff!=0:
    dayout += monthdiff*30 #or 31, depending on the month. Just add an if/else

weeks = ((dayout-dayin)//7)+1 #For python2.7 use only one slash
```

And then your if/else with the colour changing function. Be careful with January too, just add one if more. And I guess you can parse the IN and OUT strings to get the month and day yourself.

Comment: The `self.status_color.config(bg='red')` works. The thing is that with that `.config` you can't change the previous `grey` marked status, which is the aim of the question.

Comment: @Borja Man, then I don't get what you want... Do you want a function that takes the IN and OUT dates and then changes the color? Because I thought you already had one, or at least it wasn't that clear in your question...

Comment: @borja: your comment is unclear. You can change the color of just about everything -- there's nothing about calling the `config` method that prevents you from setting the color of other widgets as well.

Comment: @JGallo Yes, exactly that. I think it's clear if you read the entire question, or if you just run the code. The image that is attached to the post is just a Photoshoped image of the desired solution. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @BryanOakley The thing is that you have already created the `grey` buttons at the time you create the first time the entrys. With the `.config. method thanges the color just of the new ones.

Comment: @Borja: I still don't understand your comment. You can change the color of the gray ones. I don't understand why you think you can't. If you created it, you can change it.